# This program written in C is not giving proper output

Tags: c, pointers, codeblocks

This is a program to convert the letters of a sting into uppercase or lowercase.I don't know what's wrong with this code.When I run it,it omits the first letter of the string.Like if I give the string "Lets go out",the output is
"ETS GO OUT"("L" gets excluded which is not supposed to happen) when converted to uppercase and "ts go out"("le" gets excluded which is not supposed to happen) when converted to lower case.I use codeblocks. Please some one help me out :'(

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80],*p;

    printf("Enter A String\n");

    gets(str);

    p=str;

    while(*p)
        *p++=toupper(*p);

    printf("After uppercase conversion: %s\n",str);

    p=str;

    while(*p)
        *p++=tolower(*p);

    printf("After lowercase conversion: %s\n",str);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use `gets`

Comment: In the expression `*p++ = tolower(*p)`, what do you expect the value of `p` to be on the RHS?

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loops are equivalent to the following code:

```
while (*p)
{
    *p = tolower( *(p+1) );
    p = p+1;
}
```

So to fix this, you can use a `for` loop for example, like so:

```
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80],*p;

    printf("Enter A String\n");

    gets(str);

    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++)
        *p = toupper(*p);

    printf("After uppercase conversion: %s\n",str);

    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++)
        *p = tolower(*p);

    printf("After lowercase conversion: %s\n",str);


    return 0;
}
```